# Laravel NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, xampp, route

Tinha um projeto em minha maquina onde criei o laravel via

> $ laravel new aplicacao

Copiei este projeto para outra maquina com o xamp perfeito igual o da maquina de deseolvimento, porem quando vou acessar a rota

> Route::get('/teste/teste', function () {
>       echo 'Ola Mundo';
>   });

Ele me retorna

> (1/1) NotFoundHttpException
>
> in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
>   at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))in Router.php (line 548)

Porem se eu acessar

> Route::get('/', function () { echo 'Ola Mundo'; });

Sem os parametros na url ele retorna o Ola mundo.

Ta tentei de tudo

> composer update
>
> php artisan cache:clear

Mas nada funciona, alguem pode me ajudar ?

Abracos

Comment: Poste todas as rotas e ali nao é echo e return.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, estava com o mesmo problema e consegui solucionar, siga os seguintes passos:

1. Antes de criar o controlle defina o namespace do teu projeto.

   → Para alterar o "namespace" padrão do laravel usamos o seguite comando:

   $ php artisan app:name nome_do_seu_projeto

   Ps.: Insira em "nome_do_seu_projeto" o nome que vc criou com "laravel new ..."
     Ex.:
         `php artisan app:name project`
2. Agora podemos criar o controller, como exemplo fiz assim em "\app\Http\Controllers\IndexController.php":

```
namespace project\Http\Controllers;

class IndexController extends Controller {
  # Método para retornar a view principal
  public function index() {

    # Retornar a view principal:
    return view('index');
  }
}
```

3. Agora iremos definir uma rota para redirecionar e utilizar o controller e o métoso que criamos em "\routes\web.php":

      `Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');`

4. Por fim, crie a view para mostrar a informação em "\resources\views\index.php".

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┓ 
  Pronto!!!
  Fuiz...
  Rsrsrsr
┗━━━━┳━━━━━┛ 
╭  ┃ 
┫╰╯┣╯  
╰┳┳╯ .
```